# How to use WriteProgressCommand in a PowerShell C# cmdlet?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-4.0

**Updated.** I created a PowerShell 3.0 `cmdlet` using C#/.Net 4.0 in Visual Studio 2010. It works fine. But the `cmdlet` takes a while and I want to add a progress bar.

The MSDN documentation is vague on WriteProgressCommand. Here is the link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.writeprogresscommand.completed(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.writeprogresscommand.completed%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The code below shows what I want to do. Basically do some processing under `ProcessRecord()`. Then every second update the progress bar. Not sure how to display the progress bar. Help?

```
[System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet(System.Management.Automation.VerbsCommon.Get, "StatusBar")]
public class GetStatusBarCommand : System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a record-by-record processing functionality for the cmdlet.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        WriteProgressCommand progress = new WriteProgressCommand();

        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            progress.PercentComplete = i;
        }

        progress.Completed = true;
        this.WriteObject("Done.");
        return;
    }
}

// Commented out thanks to Graimer's answer 
// [System.Management.Automation.CmdletAttribute("Write", "Progress")]
// public sealed class WriteProgressCommand : System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet { }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tested cmdlet developing for 10min now and figured out how the progressbar works. I couldn't even add that WriteProgressCommand class(but then again I'm a programming noob). What I did get to work though was the following:

```
protected override void ProcessRecord()
      {
         ProgressRecord myprogress = new ProgressRecord(1, "Testing", "Progress:");

          for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
          {
              myprogress.PercentComplete = i;
              Thread.Sleep(100);
              WriteProgress(myprogress);
          }

             WriteObject("Done.");
      }
```

ProgressRecord stores the progress-definition and you call a WriteProgress command to update the shell(powershell window) with the newly updated progressdata. "1" in the constructor is just an id.

Comment: Hrm. So my original code was broke because I pulled in WriteProgressCommand as a public sealed class. I took that out and suddenly the PercentComplete property appeared. That's cool. Next problem: the progress bar is not showing up.

Comment: ok. I haven't tried it in C# so don't know how it works there. one correction to my "answer". Activity and status ("Progress:") IS required, at least when you do it directly in powershell. So try including an activity/"main objective" if you haven't already.

Comment: WriteProgressCommand progress = new WriteProgressCommand(); progress.Activity = "Running . . ."; progress.Status = "Running . . ."; // Still no progress bar. Thats strange.

Comment: I'm out. Now I can't even get my sample ps-script to work on my computer for some reason. I'll take a chair as an spectator. :P

Comment: I gave it a try using c# and replaced my answer. This works on Windows8 PS3.0. Used an getprocess01 sample from microsoft as template. Does it help you? : )

Comment: @Graimer for  WriteProgressCommand You need to add a reference C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll